# Django: create Textarea widget with ManytoMany for ModelFom to add data line by line

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, modelform

I have ModelFom for model with ManytoMany field:

```
class UserprojectForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Userproject
    fields = ['name', 'user', 'description', 'source_name', 'vk_groups', 'fb_groups', 'date_updated', 'date_until'] 
    # widgets = {
    #     'vk_groups': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 10}),
    #     'source_name': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 5}),
    # }

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(UserprojectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['vk_groups'].queryset = self.instance.vk_groups.all()
```

I want to allow users to enter data to Textarea line by line by hitting Enter from keyboard. Then data will be save to manytomany field.

I cannot find such widget for django!

Then i want to have this textarea in create and update views:

```
class UserprojectCreate(CreateView):
model = Userproject
#form_class = UserprojectForm
template_name = 'userproject_form.html'
success_url = reverse_lazy('userproject_list')
fields = ['name', 'description', 'vk_groups', 'source_name',  'fb_groups', 'date_updated'] 

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.user = self.request.user
    return super(UserprojectCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Now to achieve this i am using simple forms, but it is a headache to save data from form:

```
class VkwallpostgetForm(SexyModelForm):
    vk_groups= ['https://vk.com/southpark', 'https://vk.com/graph']
    vk_groups = '\r\n'.join(u'%s'%(x) for x in vk_groups) # to show data line by line
```

The main problem now is that using CreateView or UpdateView doesnot allow for user to enter data, he can only choose from existing.

Comment: You can make a widget, not hard to do

Comment: @LorenzoPeña Could you explain in more detail?

Comment: Ok, nevermind the widget, just don't handle the m2m relation in the `ModelForm`, use a custom `TextField` in the form and create a custom function in the form to parse the data entered, for each line detect if the model exists in database, otherwise create it. With the final list of related items, save the original instance.

Comment: @LorenzoPeña now i am doing exactly as you described, but this approach is hard, i need manually do save m2m objects, and so on. I assumed there are some mature approach